# Installing PHP DOM functions on Apache

Tags: php, apache, dom

I have just moved my code over to a new server (running on Apache 2.2.3), and PHP's DOM functions are now returning "Fatal error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found".

I did some research and it appears that the installation I am now on does not have PHP's DOM functions enabled.

I need to enable these functions, so what is the quickest way to go about this? Is it doable from a configuration file or will it require installation of extensions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is PHP compiled with `--disable-dom` (check your `phpinfo()`)? If PHP is compiled without DOM support you'll have to recompile PHP or find a precompiled binary which suits your needs.
The manual clearly states that there are [no installation needed](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dom.installation.php) in PHP5 and [no configuration options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dom.configuration.php).

If you are for some reason running PHP 4, you should really upgrade to PHP 5. I you only want to enable the DOM XML extension in PHP4, read [this manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxml.installation.php)

Comment: Hi, and thank you for your answer.

I managed to sort this problem out; PHP was indeed compiled without DOM support. Thankfully though a recompile was not needed, and I used yum to install "php-xml". This fixed my problem.